# GWT Lifecycle Flow

Tags: gwt

Hi i am new to GWT but i have gone through and understood the Functionalities and what GWT do ! but i was not able to understand the Lifecycle or Work Flow of GWT when we will create a project

Example 

 I have created the GWT project so after i deploy it from where it will start like

> web.xml or *.gwt.xml

and where it will go to 
Please guide me through this.what is the Flow for GWT from where it will start and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the GWT bootstrap process. It is explained quite well in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#What%27s_with_all_the_cache/nocache_stuff_and_weird_filenames), see the points 1 to 5.

Mind that the above explanations are only correct for production mode (once you app is compiled and deployed). Running the app from your IDE using the GWT developer mode is a whole different story.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds to me a little bit ambiguous or too much generic.

For a better understanding of GWT Projects you have to read this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects

Answer (score 0):

from gwt.xml you will specify the entry point class which is the starting point of the gwt. The entry point class contains the onload module function which will be called first. So from onmoduleload() you will start writing the first code to execute.

GWT UI is build over the root panel, so all the widgets that you put will bind over the root panel in the onmoduleload() code.

Hope this helps for first shot

Comment: So then what about the welcome tag file in web.xml which points out to the  module.html in basic ? So it will not enter into web.xml first ?